# Facebook Ads API - Removing many users from a Custom Audience

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, python-requests, facebook-ads-api

I am using Python requests library to build an Ads Management software tool. I have successfully added around 50 users to a Custom Audience using a `POST` to `/<custom-audience-id>/users`. The users were added using 'md5'-hashed iOS ID's and the `users` list was sent in the body, using the `data` parameter of `requests.post()`.

```
# assuming endpoint and parameters are defined up here

# list of users
users = [{"mobile_advertiser_id": hashlib.md5(ios_id).hexdigest()} for ios_id in ios_id_list]

# supply that list in the body of a POST
data = {
    "users": json.dumps(users)
}
requests.post(endpoint, params=parameters, data=data)
```

Now I'd like to remove them. I send a `DELETE` to the same endpoint (`/<custom-audience-id>/users`) with the same list of users used in the add above. With the users list in the body of the call, (the `data` parameter of `requests.delete()`) as in the add above, I get the error response:

```
{'error': {'message': 'An unknown error has occurred.', 'code': 1, 'type': 'OAuthException'}}
```

So I instead put the users list in the `params` argument of `requests.delete()`, so they would be specified in the query string, and as expected I get

```
{'status_code': 414, 'reason': 'Request-URI Too Large'}
```

because the users list is a couple hundred long so the query string was too long. I tried a bunch of different lengths and it turns out I can get 103 users in the users list and it works perfectly!

So my question is, is there a way to remove many (like, thousands) of users from a Custom Audience with a single request, or is it the case that to remove 10,000 users I would have to send 100 DELETE's, removing about 100 users each time, by putting the users list in the query string?

Comment: are you sure you included the user access token in the params? You should put the users in the data section of the post. Please post the section of code.

Comment: also, you don't need to hash the mobile_advertiser_id

Comment: Re hashing mobile_advertisement_id: But I *can* hash it, right? For example, if some tracking only gives the hashed id's for some users then their raw id's wouldn't be available.

Comment: @tscizzle did you ever find a solution for this (beyond drastically limiting the batch size)? I've just hit the same issue (from C# code). I don't see a way around it since DELETE works differently from POST.

Comment: Bad new is: i don't have a more elegant solution. I just dramatically limited the batch size, as you say. Good news is: that works pretty well. I do batches of 80.